# Trying to modify Active Directory with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm attempting to go through and modify multiple users in AD with PowerShell.  I want to add/update a field to give the full path to their computer.  Hete's the script I have so far...

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase 'OU=CCG,OU=CCG-Users,OU=CCG-All-PCs-and-Users,OU=CCG,OU=Departments,DC=serve,DC=group,DC=net' |
Set-ADUser -Add @{OtherLoginWorkstations='($_.samaccountname).serve.group.net'}
```

The best i've come up with is the field changed to ".serve.group.net" but did not include the SAMACCOUNTNAME (which is the name of their computer) at the beginning.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

To reference the pipeline element with `$_` you need to use a `Foreach-Object` loop

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase 'OU=CCG,OU=CCG-Users,OU=CCG-All-PCs-and-Users,OU=CCG,OU=Departments,DC=serve,DC=group,DC=net' |
    ForEach-Object {
        Set-ADUser Identity $_.SamAccountName -Add @{OtherLoginWorkstations = $_.samaccountname + ".serve.group.net"}
    }
```

Comment: I tried that as well and just ended up with "($_.samaccountname).serve.group.net"  Its not actually grabbing the samaccountname item, just putting that text itself in the field

Comment: Stupi me. When you like to use $_ you have to use a Foreach-Object. Otherwise there is no Pipeline-Variable. I corrected the code in the answer.

Comment: Ahh, it makes sense to have to loop through it.  However when I run it now, it asks me to supply values for the identity.

Not sure what it's asking for there or how to get it to just run through the OU and process this on each user.  Any ideas?

Comment: You're right. I forgot this part when copied the code here, sorry. Maybe I should answer question that late at night.  ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Change the single quotes to double quotes and make sure you use a subexpression `$()`:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase 'OU=CCG,OU=CCG-Users,OU=CCG-All-PCs-and-Users,OU=CCG,OU=Departments,DC=serve,DC=group,DC=net' |
  Set-ADUser -Add @{OtherLoginWorkstations="$($_.samaccountname).serve.group.net"}
```